# Same File giving different output on intellij and cmd

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea

A friend of mine was having some issues with her project,she sent the files for me to debug. I am not sure but from the looks of it she doesn't use any ide, so when I got the files I made an Intellij project and copy pasted the files there.

When I ran the files on intellij it gave me a filenotfound exception, that was not been given in cmd.So I added the correct file path.

the file involves multithreading.

After that, I ran the file on intellij and it gave the desired output.

However, the file is giving a completely different output if I run it from cmd.

```
//This is the part from main where a thread is being made 
Event e = new Restart(gc, 0, filename);
    gc.addEvent(e);
    new Thread(e).start();
```

In the restart class there is where the issue was:

```
public void getEvents(String filename) {

// open the file and read it using Scanner
try {
  /** The file containing event details */
  File myFile = new File(filename);
  /** The Scanner object to read file */
  Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myFile);
  /** Current event being analyzed by Scanner */
  String myEvent;
  /** The delay with which the event will occur in ms  */
  long delayTime;



  while ((myReader.hasNextLine()) 
    && ((myEvent = myReader.nextLine()) != null)) {
    int equal = myEvent.indexOf('=');
    int comma = myEvent.indexOf(',');
    String className = myEvent.substring(equal+1, comma);
    myEvent = myEvent.substring(comma+1);
    Event e;
    
    if (myEvent.contains("rings")) {
      equal = myEvent.indexOf("=");
      comma = myEvent.indexOf(",");
      delayTime = Long.parseLong(myEvent.substring(equal+1, comma));
      myEvent = myEvent.substring(comma+1);
      equal = myEvent.indexOf("=");
      int rings = Integer.parseInt(myEvent.substring(equal+1));
      e = new Bell(delayTime);
      gc.addEvent(e);
      new Thread(e).start();
      while(rings-- > 1) {
        e = new Bell(delayTime += 2000);
        gc.addEvent(e);
        new Thread(e).start();
      }
    } 
    else {
      equal = myEvent.indexOf("=");
      delayTime = Long.parseLong(myEvent.substring(equal+1));
      Class<Event> myClass = (Class<Event>)Class.forName("tme4." + className);
      Constructor<Event> ctor = myClass.getConstructor(long.class);
      e = ctor.newInstance(delayTime);
      gc.addEvent(e);
      new Thread(e).start();
    }
  }

  myReader.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();;
}
```

}

I only changed the first few lines:
From This:

```
 File myFile = new File(filename);
  /** The Scanner object to read file */
  Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myFile);

 Path currentPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
  Path filePath = Paths.get(currentPath.toString(),filename);
```

To This:

```
filePath=Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Admin\\IdeaProjects\\summayah\\src\\examples1.txt");
  System.out.println(filePath);
  File myFile = new File(filename);
  /** The Scanner object to read file */
  Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myFile);
```

Can someone kindly help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code so we can see what could be the problem. If the program involves multithreading, remember that the output can change executing multiple times if you don't differently cover this behavior.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. I’m afraid you’re going to have to be far more specific with detail before anyone is going to be in a position to be able to help you.

Comment: I have added parts of the files which I think are relevant. sry for the late reply.
And @Gius you are right, the program did change it outputs once.

Comment: Possibly unrelated but instead of `Paths.get(currentPath.toString(),filename);` it's better to do `currentPath.resolve(filename)`

Comment: @BenAnderson ,tried that, it doesnt work.